# When Alice has got a cold, we could say "Alice is sick", "Alice feels ill", or some other expressions?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ill) gives this meaning of ill

> not feeling well, or suffering from a disease

and this meaning of sick

> physically or mentally ill; not well or healthy

So, when someone, say Alice, has got a cold, which one of following is more appropriate?

```
Alice is sick
Alice feels ill
```

or some other expression?

When I say Alice is sick (or some other more appropriate word), I would like to have my audience realize that Alice may have got a cold, other than "Alice is in trouble, Alice is insane".

Comment: Do you mean "Alice has got ***a*** cold" ? Both the sentences work, also "Alice is unwell."

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your reminder. I've updated OP. I heard about that "ill" or "sick", only one of them, has another meaning, like someone behaves badly like Alice has problem, Alice is in trouble, is it?

Comment: That is not what you asked. You can use either of those sentences, but "Alice is sick" also means that she perhaps has a horrible sense of humour. But in effect, that's the same meaning but a different ailment.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is definitely what I asked. When I say Alice is sick (or some other more appropriate word), I would like to have my audience realize that Alice may have got a cold, other than "Alice is in trouble, Alice is insane".

Comment: Note that *sick* and *ill* may have different connotations in the UK and US. There are a lot of articles on this topic, but I recommend http://ldoceonline.com's entries on *sick* and *ill*, http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/sick-and-ill, and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/ill-or-sick.

Comment: You could say that Alice caught a cold (idiomatic expression for getting a cold)

Answer (score 1):

*Ill* and *sick* are both adjectives that mean ‘not in good health’. We use both ill and sick after a verb such as be, become, feel, look or seem.

In British English *sick* means ‘to vomit’ in British English. In American English it means more generally ‘to be unwell’.

You can say also not healthy or not well.